# Need advise developing an Online Exams Platform using PHP, Javascript & AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I desperately need advise developing an Online Exams Platform using PHP, Javascript & Ajax.

My problem is I can't figure out the correct methodology for taking the exam procedure, here are my problems and the options I'm thinking of:

I'm not sure whether I shall load all questions at once from the database and toggle between them using java script, save student answers and then submit the result using AJAX, that way no connection to the server will be required during the exam which makes it faster and more importantly the exam will still run if the internet goes down, and YES we have terrible internet connection.

Or shall I load each question independently and save the answer to a table and load another question with ajax? but that way what if the connection slows down or even worse goes down?

Any ideas anyone?
Thank You,

Comment: didn't you answer your own question? If your source of internet is so unreliable using offline functionality as much as possible should be good.

Comment: You cannot load each question independently if you have a bad internet connection. Imagine you are a student in your exam and you answer like 5 of 10 questions and you cannot get the 6th due to bad internet connection, ;)

Comment: Try to save student every answer as soon as possible to avoid losing previous answers because of browser crashing (or accidental closing). If internet is unreliable then saving should be independent from form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The advantages of the first solution are greater than the second if we are considering bad internet connection as an issue. But I think there are two more consideration that we may do.

1. Local

First, if the Platform is intended for internal use only, it would be much better to run it from a local server, avoiding connection issues as all the computers will connect via LAN. In this situation, you may apply what solution you'll prefer, without having to worry about net performance.

2. Internet

However, if you plan to use the Platform over the internet, the best choice would be to replicate information about answers to make it fail-proof.
After loading all the questions with an AJAX call (which now is the best approach), from time to time you should do a backup of the answers in Javascript using **local storage** (http://www.html5rocks.com/it/features/storage), so if the final submit goes wrong you can retry as many times as you want and even recover the information in case the net is down for good and the browser has been already closed.

Another good practice may be to send **silent AJAX calls** towards the server from time to time, storing the answers as the test goes on. These calls will not populate the same database as the final submit, instead a temporary one. They are more like a backup: in case the net goes dark, pc turns off or any other kind of problem, you can restore the situation for the user and recover the answers.

Remember, in both local storage and silent calls, to always store the **timestamp**, so you can easily tell when that save operation occured and decide whether to trust the local storage or the temporary info on the server while reconstructing the exam panel page.

So you have now three different source for storing your answers: local storage, temporary table and the real results table. This should cover most fail cases out there, giving you a better chance to avoid loss of information.

Comment: Thank you i never knew local storage via HTML is possible..